# Adding Dynamic Stylesheet

Tags: plugin-development

I have added my dynamically generated stylesheet by this way.

```
add_action( 'parse_request', 'my_custom_wp_request' );
function my_custom_wp_request( $wp ) {
    if (
        !empty( $_GET['my-custom-content'] )
        && $_GET['my-custom-content'] == 'css'
    ) {
        # get theme options
        header( 'Content-Type: text/css' );
        require dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/css/style-options.php';
        exit;
    }
}
```

And to hook into theme I did

```
function my_login_css() {
?>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href="<?php bloginfo( 'url' ); ?>/?my-custom-content=css" />
<?
}

add_action('wp_footer', 'my_login_css');
```

My question: Is there any way to hook stylesheet other than this old fashioned way, like `wp_register_style` or `wp_enqueue_style`?

Answer (score 1):

This is the recommended way to add a custom or second style sheet for child themes:

```
function custom_style_sheet() {

wp_enqueue_style( 'custom-styling', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/custom.css' );

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_style_sheet');
```

You can also add style sheets conditionally http://wpsites.net/wordpress-themes/second-style-sheet-theme/